# Not supported between instances of str and int

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code

```
data['A'].loc[data['A']>30] = 'high'
```

work for me. However when i used

```
data['A'].loc[data['A']<30] = 'low'
```

An error message pop up

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I wanted to have `'high'` for values higher than 30 and `'low'` for values lower than 30 on the same pandas column.

Comment: can you share your dataframes?

Comment: Comparisons between different data types are no longer allowed in Python 3. That's what your error seems to say. Maybe you could add some more code to your question?

Comment: You first set half of your data to be a string (i.e. `'low'`) then you compare these strings with the number 30. This operation is not allowed...

Comment: ['A'] contains integers and float, but wanted grouping them into high and low for values < and > 30. Its actually a machine learning (classification) assignment I am working on

Comment: As people asked you should show us a sample of your dataframe / data

Comment: try with np.select ?

Comment: Array(['high',  20.426, 14.46, 'high', 'high', 15.1], dtype=object)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a manual approach, use `pd.cut`:

```
pd.cut(data['A'], [float('-inf'), 30, float('inf')], labels=['low', 'high'])
```

Example:

```
s = pd.Series([-10, 40, 70, 60, 20])
pd.cut(s, [float('-inf'), 30, float('inf')], labels=['low', 'high'])
```

Output:

```
0     low
1    high
2    high
3    high
4     low
```

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote this line:

`data['A'].loc[data['A']>30] = 'high'`

you transformed your `A` column to a column of type `object` containing `int` and `str`

When you write your second line

`data['A'].loc[data['A']<30] = 'low'`

pandas goes through the complete column (including that were `>30` that have had their values updated to `'high'`)

the best approach would be to use `pd.cut` as mentioned by *gmds*.

You can also create a second column then drop it in the end.

```
data['B'] = 'low'
data.loc[data.A>30, 'B'] = 'high'
data['A'] = data['B']
data.drop(columns=['B'], inplace=True)
```

Not the most elegant solution but it works